# What are the methods of right knowledge (Pramana) according to different schools of Hindu Philosophies?

Tags: vedanta, sankhya, shad-darshana, nyaya, vaisheshika

For example, Samkhya admits perception, inference and Shabda (verbal testimony) as valid proofs. However, this is not universal in all schools. The accepted Pramanas vary between different schools. I am looking for authoritative verses from respective Sutras or Karikas of different schools describing the types of Pramanas. Please quote only primary sources.

Comment: First blockquote of this Q---- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19727/4732

Comment: Also quite possible that this is asked already among ---- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=pramana