# What is the principle behind Hindu deities having more than two hands and more than one head?

Tags: gods

Many of Hindu deities are having more than two hands and more than one head. What is the principle behind this?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/why-do-the-gods-look-like-human-beings

Answer (score 0):

A deity is the manifestation of god which varies from place to place and time to time. The multi armed deities are the results of experiences of Rushi's and monks of Hinduism. No one consciousness is same as others, so the experience also will change so that one god may have many types of deities. There may be Laxmi deity with two hands or four hands. Hinduism given freedom to people which they can made their own manifestation of god in the form of deity.

Comment: these are only stories in puranas, no puran is authentic. in vedas nothing is mentioned multi organs.

Comment: @ManojPilania I hope you know Purusha Suktam where God is said to have thousands of arms and eyes. Thousands are not multiple for you?